# replace tilde to shift key in macbook

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

I try to change tilde key to shift.

I have success in it, but only for russian language.

I used `KeyRemap4MacBook` for it.

[image: tilde to shift in KeyRemap4MacBook]

When I switch language to english this substitution stops working. How to make it work in both languages?

**UPDATE**

From `KeyRemap4MacBook eventViewer` I found that my target key code is `DANISH_DOLLAR` 
[image: KeyRemap4MacBook eventViewer]

And I set `private.xml` (`~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`) accordingly:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>TildeToShift</name>
    <identifier>TildeToShift</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DANISH_DOLLAR, KeyCode::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

I clicked `ReloadXML` and watched results: nothing changed. I press my target key + `a`, expecting to get `A`(shift+a), but instead see `§a`
[image: KeyRemap4MacBook eventViewer]

**Update 2**

Finally target key code is `KeyCode::BACKQUOTE` but not `KeyCode::DANISH_DOLLAR` although `EventViwer` showed `DANISH_DOLLAR` when I clicked target key.  This is because I swapped `Tilde` and Section keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>TildeToShift</name>
    <identifier>TildeToShift</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BACKQUOTE, KeyCode::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: I copied this code to my `private.xml`, saved it and pressed button `Reload Xml` in `KeyRemap4MacBook`, but have no result. This key works as usual, not like `shift`.

Comment: @efr On my keyboard, you hold shift and press the backquote key to get a tilde. Please use the EventViewer (In Terminal: `open /Applications/KeyRemap4MacBook.app/Contents/Applications/EventViewer.app`) to get the key code of the key that you wish to change to shift.

Comment: using `EventViewer` I detected target key code, edit `private.xml` but still no result (see update above please)

Comment: @efr Don't forget to enable the new TildeToShift option in KeyRemap4MacBook's preferences after you've reloaded the private.xml.